# Group by statement column name resolution

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query like this (more columns in reality)

```
select 
    custom_amend_column_function(colname) as colname
from source_table
group by colname
```

I've used this construct a lot.It appears to have always used the output from the function rather than the input to group data by.
Now for the first time today I have run this statement directly into a new table like this:

```
create table new_table as
select 
    custom_amend_column_function(colname) as colname
from source_table
group by colname
```

Curiously by adding the first line, I am getting an error message that my query is using an ambiguous column name in the group statement.

As group by can use new column names (ie. the below works) I always expected that group by will first use the columns defined in the select statement and then look at the underlying table(s) if it cannot find the names.

```
select 
    custom_amend_column_function(colname) as new_colname
from source_table
group by new_colname
```

Am I right? Is the error message right? I cannot find any place this is documented either for the SQL standard or for MySQL.

I know I could avoid this by just creating a new column name, but I want to figure this out as I may need to review existing queries if it is indeed ambiguous.

Comment: This is just not true. `CREATE TABLE .. AS` generally will just use query result. Once it's successful, creation will be done. More, `GROUP BY` in your case will use __original column__ to group data and __not__ output from the function. Proof: [for 5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e663c/1); [for 5.5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e663c/1); [for 5.1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e663c/1) - as you can see, it's working fine both for DDL and for name resolution, which will be performed by original column (since we may see multiple rows for same function output, but different original values)

Comment: As I said in the question I *never validated* if the result of the grouping was based on the table column or the query output, but made an assumption. Adding the `create table [table_name] as` at the start of the query definitely added a warning to the query that the column definition was ambiguous. If the latter is indeed the case .. . 1) Why is this warning only coming up when you create the table and not when running a select 2) Is the precedence of table column vs. query column documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trace the problem do an

```
 EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...
```

On your query. Beside the normal output this will give you a warning containing the query as it is seen by the optimizer. All implicit renaming is done here, so you can see why the column name is ambiguous.

I think you can solve this by saying

```
 ... GROUP BY 1
```

instead of providing the column name in the group by.